# Android CalanderView to change programmatically

Tags: android, datepicker

I am creating a calendar view using DatePicker. I have 4 button. first 2 buttons is for the user to select year. For example, if calendar is currently showing 2013, if user press first left button, i want it to show 2012 and if user press first right button, I want it to show 2014. Basically, button s are for incrementing and decrementing years and months. However, I cannot find way to programmatically change Calendar. Here is my code. When I used CalanderView, it slow down the app. That why I am using CalanderView mode from DatePicker. Please let me know if any of you know better way for this.

```
          android:background="#ff46554b"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" android:weightSum="1">

<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>


<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Medium Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"/>
    <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Button"
            android:id="@+id/button2" android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>


<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <DatePicker
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"

            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:calendarViewShown="true"
            android:spinnersShown="false"

            android:scaleX="1.3"
            android:scaleY="1.3"
            android:id="@+id/datePicker"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:minWidth="100dp"
            android:minHeight="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="53dp">
    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="cancel"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"

            android:background="@drawable/refreshbutton"
            android:id="@+id/cancel"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="select"
           android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/refreshbutton"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/select"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="61dp"
              android:layout_weight=".1"
              android:background="#ff5c625f"
              android:weightSum="1">
    <com.mopub.mobileads.MoPubView
            android:id="@+id/adview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `findViewById()` to get the Button and the DatePicker, then set the button's `setOnClickListener` to change the year using DatePicker's `updateDate(int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`:

```
Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.BUTTON_ID_HERE);
DatePicker d = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.DATEPICKER_ID_HERE);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         int year = d.getYear();
         int month = d.getMonth();
         int day = d.getDayOfMonth();

         d.updateDate(year, month, day);
     }
 });
```

Button: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html

DatePicker: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html

Comment: Do you know how I can show day like (Monday, Tuesday etc..)? In the IDE, date picker CalanderView show days of the month. However, when i run on phone, it does't show day of the month at all. Thanks.